# How can I mount folder correctly in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to run nodered in my minikube kubernetes cluster ("cluster", its one node :D).

The docker command to do this is by example:

```
docker run -it -p 1880:1880 -v /home/user/node_red_data:/data --name mynodered nodered/node-red
```

But I'm not running it in docker, I'm trying to run it in minikube. The documentation of minikube states that /data on the host is persisted. So what I wanted was a /data/nodered to be mounted up as /data on the nodered container.

I started with adding a storage class:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Then added persistent storage:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: small-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - minikube
```

Then a persistent volume claim for the nodered:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nodered-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

And then the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nodered
  name: nodered
spec:
  replicas: 1
  volumes:
    - name: nodered-claim
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: nodered-claim
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodered
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodered
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodered
        image: nodered/node-red:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1880
      volumeMounts:
      - name: nodered-claim
        mountPath: "/data"
        subPath: "nodered"
```

I've checked kubernetes dasboard and everything is green and volume is bound. I created a simple http service in nodered and deployed it. It's running but nothing is saved. So if the deployment goes down and gets redeployed it will be empty.

I've checked the /data and /data/nodered folders on the minikube instance running in docker but they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment spec should return error, try the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nodered
  name: nodered
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodered
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodered
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodered
        image: nodered/node-red:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1880
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nodered-claim
          mountPath: /data/nodered
          # subPath: nodered <-- not needed in your case
      volumes:
      - name: nodered-claim
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nodered-claim
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How does setting mountPath to /data/nodered mount it as /data in the nodered container? Thats the requirement. I need to mount /data/nodered on the host to /data on the nodered container

Comment: Note local path refer to path on the host while mountPath refer to path in the container. Base on your original spec, your PV represent /data on the host and you want to mount it as /data/nodered in the container. Have you commented the opposite?